# Summarise Data using group_by across several columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a dataframe where all columns are factors:

```
set.seed(123)
gender <- sample(1:2,12,replace=T)
country <- c('FIN', 'FIN', 'EST', 'NIG','NIG','JAM', 'FIN', 'NIG', 'EST', 'NIG','NIG','JAM','FIN', 'FIN', 'EST', 'NIG','NIG','JAM', 'FIN', 'NIG', 'EST', 'NIG','NIG','JAM')
a <- sample(1:5,24,,replace=T)
b <- sample(1:5,24,,replace=T)
c <- sample(1:5,24,,replace=T)
d <- sample(1:5,24,,replace=T)
# Join the variables to create a data frame
df <- data.frame(gender,country,a,b,c,d)

df <- df %>% mutate_at(c("gender","country","a","b","c","d"), as.factor)
```

I want a table that will give a proportion percentage and n across every column a:d by Gender and Region so the end result would look something like this:
[image]

I've done this for **a** using the code (but I want to do this also for all the other columns b,c,d without replicating the code):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(gender,country,a) %>%
  summarise(totaln=n()) %>% 
  group_by(country,gender) %>% 
  mutate(percentage=totaln/sum(totaln)*100)
```

so for a I get this:

```
   gender country a     totaln percentage
   <fct>  <fct>   <fct>  <int>      <dbl>
 1 1      EST     1          2       50  
 2 1      EST     3          1       25  
 3 1      EST     4          1       25  
 4 1      FIN     1          1       25  
 5 1      FIN     2          3       75  
 6 1      NIG     1          1       25  
 7 1      NIG     2          1       25  
 8 1      NIG     3          1       25  
 9 1      NIG     4          1       25  
10 2      FIN     1          1       50  
11 2      FIN     3          1       50  
12 2      JAM     1          2       50  
13 2      JAM     3          2       50  
14 2      NIG     3          1       16.7
15 2      NIG     4          1       16.7
16 2      NIG     5          4       66.7
```

Comment: It is impossible to reproduce your data since you use randomness. Please use `set.seed` to set the start of the randomness, then rerun all of your code and interim results so that our reproduction efforts have something to compare (correctly) with.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably first want to do is to transform your data in a tidy-format by using `pivot_longer` on a:d, and then group also by this variable, from there it is almost the same code as you wrote:

```r
df_summary <- df %>% pivot_longer(c(a, b, c, d), names_to = "abcd") %>%
  group_by(gender, country, abcd, value) %>%
  summarise(totaln = n()) %>%
  group_by(country, gender, abcd) %>%
  mutate(percentag = totaln / sum(totaln) * 100)

df_summary 

#> # A tibble: 64 × 6
#> # Groups:   country, gender, abcd [24]
#>    gender country abcd  value totaln percentag
#>    <fct>  <fct>   <chr> <fct>  <int>     <dbl>
#>  1 1      EST     a     1          1        25
#>  2 1      EST     a     3          2        50
#>  3 1      EST     a     4          1        25
#>  4 1      EST     b     2          1        25
#>  5 1      EST     b     3          1        25
#>  6 1      EST     b     4          2        50
#>  7 1      EST     c     2          1        25
#>  8 1      EST     c     5          3        75
#>  9 1      EST     d     1          1        25
#> 10 1      EST     d     2          2        50
#> # … with 54 more rows
```

To create your desired output shape, you can do:

```r
df_summary %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(summary = paste0(round(percentag), "% (n = ", totaln, ")")) %>% 
  select(gender, country, abcd, value, summary) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(gender, country), values_from = summary, values_fill = "0")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: nice.. fyi, you don't need the second `group_by()` line, as the first three grouping vars are retained after the `summarize()` call

Comment: @langtang, true, but better explicit than implicit I would say.

Answer (score 2):

Two options. Both retain the `0` combinations, that can easily be `filter`ed out if needed.

1. Long format:

   ```r
   df %>%
     tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(gender, country), names_to = "ltr", values_to = "val") %>%
     group_by(gender, country, ltr) %>%
     summarize(
       totaln = sum(as.numeric(table(val))),
       percentage = 100 * as.numeric(table(val)) / totaln
     ) %>%
     ungroup()
   # `summarise()` has grouped output by 'gender', 'country', 'ltr'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
   # # A tibble: 120 x 5
   #    gender country ltr   totaln percentage
   #    <fct>  <fct>   <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>
   #  1 1      EST     a          4         50
   #  2 1      EST     a          4          0
   #  3 1      EST     a          4         25
   #  4 1      EST     a          4         25
   #  5 1      EST     a          4          0
   #  6 1      EST     b          4         25
   #  7 1      EST     b          4         50
   #  8 1      EST     b          4         25
   #  9 1      EST     b          4          0
   # 10 1      EST     b          4          0
   # # ... with 110 more rows
   ```
2. Wide format:

   ```r
   df %>%
     group_by(gender, country) %>%
     summarize(across(a:d,
       list(
         perc = ~ 100 * as.numeric(table(.)) / sum(as.numeric(table(.))), 
         total = ~ as.numeric(table(.)), 
         newval = ~ factor(names(table(.)), levels = levels(.))
       )
     )) %>%
     ungroup()
   # `summarise()` has grouped output by 'gender', 'country'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
   # # A tibble: 30 x 14
   #    gender country a_perc a_total a_newval b_perc b_total b_newval c_perc c_total c_newval d_perc d_total d_newval
   #    <fct>  <fct>    <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>   
   #  1 1      EST         50       2 1            25       1 1            75       3 1             0       0 1       
   #  2 1      EST          0       0 2            50       2 2             0       0 2            50       2 2       
   #  3 1      EST         25       1 3            25       1 3             0       0 3            25       1 3       
   #  4 1      EST         25       1 4             0       0 4             0       0 4            25       1 4       
   #  5 1      EST          0       0 5             0       0 5            25       1 5             0       0 5       
   #  6 1      FIN         25       1 1            25       1 1            25       1 1             0       0 1       
   #  7 1      FIN         75       3 2            50       2 2            25       1 2            50       2 2       
   #  8 1      FIN          0       0 3             0       0 3            25       1 3            25       1 3       
   #  9 1      FIN          0       0 4             0       0 4            25       1 4            25       1 4       
   # 10 1      FIN          0       0 5            25       1 5             0       0 5             0       0 5       
   # # ... with 20 more rows
   ```